# list data in between from and to dates for current date

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table with some date range assigned to user. i need to get details of user for whom current day is assigned.

```
user      from-date          to-date
------------------------------
x1        12/08/2016         25/08/2016
x2        24/08/2016         30/08/2016
x3        15/08/2016         20/08/2016
x4        18/08/2016         27/08/2016
```

the above given is table details

i want to list user, x1 and x4 to be listed as it is assigned to current date(22/08/2016)

thanks in advance

Comment: How do you query this table? It's as simple as `var today = DateTime.Now.Date` and `.Where(u => u.FromDate >= today&& DateTime.Now <= today)`.

Comment: What have you tried? What is the exact problem you are having doing this? It seems to be some pretty basic LINQ you are after so do you just not understand LINQ or are you having some problems with using `Where`?

Answer (score 0):

A simple place to start with linq will be `Where`:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
var result = dbContext.table.Where(item => item.FromDate >= date && item.ToDate < date)
                            .Select(item => item.User);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
var users = dbContext.Users.Where(user.FromDate < DateTime.Now 
                               && user.ToDate > DateTime.Now)
                           .Select(user=>user.User);
```

I have supposed that you have a context class through which you speak with your database and this context class has a connection to the `Users` table. Even if this is not the case, if you change accordingly the first part, `dbContext.Users`, the rest part is that you want (a few renamings may be needed)